# How can I use Stream to traverse a tree in Scala?

Tags: scala, stream

I have a simple file system abstraction:

```
trait PathItem { val label: String }

case class PathEnd(label: String, uri: String) extends PathItem

case class PathDirectory(
  label: String = "", 
  contents: List[PathItem] = List.empty[PathItem]
) extends PathItem
```

With this structure I can build up an arbitrarily complex tree of subdirectories (PathDirectory) and files (PathEnd).

How could I use Scala Streams to extract a list of the "files" something like this:

```
getFileStream( rootDir ).foreach( f => println(f.uri) )
getFileStream( rootDir ).find( _.uri == "someTargetURI" )

// where getFileStream creates a Stream[PathEnd] given a starting rootDir
```

Passing through the tree like this would be kinda cool, but I'm not understanding how to create a Stream for this from the scaladoc.

(I know I can just write a simple recursive function, but I'm trying to grok Streams here.)

Comment: You can pretty much treat a `Stream` (or an `Iterator`) the same as you would a `List`, and subsequent elements will be computed lazily. EDIT: a good primer: http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-use-stream-class-lazy-list-scala-cookbook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you can essentially treat a `Stream` the same as you would a `List` and you'll get the desired lazily evaluated sequence. Your solution:

```
def fileStream(p: PathItem): Stream[PathEnd] = {
    p match {
        case pe: PathEnd => Stream(pe)
        case pd: PathDirectory => pd.contents.toStream.flatMap(fileStream)
    }
}
```

Note the `flatMap` to avoid creating a `Stream` of `Stream` instances.

Test:

```
scala> val pd = PathDirectory(root,List(
    PathDirectory("src",List(PathDirectory("main",List(PathEnd("file.scala","file.uri"))))),
    PathDirectory("test",List(PathDirectory("main",List(PathEnd("test.scala","test.uri")))))))
scala> fileStream(pd).foreach(println)

PathEnd(file.scala,file.uri)
PathEnd(test.scala,test.uri)
```